# SQL Parameter not found

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

**The error:**

> Procedure or Function '' expects parameter '@Param1' which was not supplied.

**An excerpt of the stored procedure:**

I have a stored procedure on a SQL Server 2012. The procedure looks something like this...

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Orders
WHERE Orders.CustomerID = @param1 AND 
    Orders.CustomerJoinDate = @param2
```

I call it from my code {Using Visual Studio 2008} like so...

**The calling method in Visual Studios:**

First I create an array of parameters I'm going to pass...

```
Dim Param() As SqlClient.SqlParameter = 
    New SqlClient.SqlParameter() 
        {
            New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Param1", Me.cmbFilter1.Text), 
            New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Param2", Me.cmbFilter2.Text)
        }
```

Then I loop through the parameters and add them to a command to be executed by a datareader.

The `mSQLCmd` is set to call the stored procedure described above...

```
mSQLCmd.Parameters.Clear()
mSQLCmd.CommandText = SQLCmd

For Each sParam As SqlClient.SqlParameter In Param
    mSQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(sParam.ParameterName, sParam.Value)
Next
```

**Error occurs when:**

I try to run `mSQL.ExecuteReader()` Can someone point me in the right direction on this? I've verified that each parameter is included in the `Param()` with the correct values.

I've also tested the stored procedure on SQL Server and verified when the two necessary parameters are provided it works correctly. Something is wrong on the vb side.

Comment: might be case sensitive....

Comment: Can you verify the command that is being executed by the SQL client? It sounds like the parameter was not included when the sp was executed.

Comment: also can you do it without the @.... I recall something like that so do `New SqlClient.SqlParameter("param1", Me.cmbFilter1.Text)`

Comment: Can you include the full definition of your procedure, not just the body?

Comment: It is just a typo? The foreach uses Param not Params

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're calling a **stored procedure**, you need to set the `CommandType` of the `SqlCommand` accordingly!

```
mSQLCmd.CommandText = SQLCmd

// add this line!
mSQLCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

Otherwise the name of the stored procedure you're trying to call is interpreted as a SQL command you're trying to execute.

Comment: Amazing you could deduce that from what I've supplied... Ahh, yes its getting a little late in the day apparently. Thank you for the hard slap to the face. ;)